Unable to connect to Redis. I am using Springboot3 and Java17 version
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis
caused by io.lettuce.core.redisconnectionexception unable to connect to hostname/ unresolved 16379
caused by java.net.socketException: Connection reset

I created Redis cluster in docker and created VPC and using this VPC i am trying to connect to Redis from SPring boot application. But I am getting below errors:org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis                                                                                                            -----------caused by io.lettuce.core.redisconnectionexception unable to connect to hostname/ unresolved 16379
------ caused by java.net.socketException: Connection reset

I think issue is getting unresolved in the url. here IpAddress should come. But I am not able to figure out why this unresolved is coming. In application.properties I am using only these 2 properties Spring.data.redis.host:hostname and Sprong.data.redis.port: 16379

Have you tried to connect to the Redis server from the same place you are running your app using some other client, e.g. redis-cli?
